# Prove that there is no finite subcover

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $I_n$ and $J_k$ be sequences of bounded intervals. $I_n$ are pairwise disjoint and  $J_k$ are open. $\ell(I)$ denotes the length of the bounded interval $I$.

Suppose $\bigcup_{n=1}^NI_n\subset\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty J_k$. Then the $J_k$ form an open cover for the set $\bigcup_{n=1}^N I_n$.

Suppose $\sum_{n=1}^N\ell(I_n)>\sum_{k=1}^M\ell(J_k)$, for any $M$. Prove that the sets ($J_k$) form an open cover for $\bigcup_{n=1}^N I_n$ that admits no finite subcover.

Comment: What is $\ell$? Lebesgue measure? Are these subsets of $\mathbb{R}^m$?

Comment: $\ell$ is the length of each (bounded) interval.

Comment: Ok, so these are intervals in $\mathbb{R}$. Another thing is that your inequality cannot possibly hold for any $M$, more precisely it doesn't hold for $M\geq N$, right?

Comment: There was a typo which I have now fixed.

Comment: Every open set in the real line is a union of disjoint open intervals. Every interval is connected. So if $\cup_{n=1}^N I_n$ was in $\cup_{i=1}^M J_i$ for some $M$, each $I_i$ would be in an open interval because of being connected, and that would contradict your hypothesis about their lengths

Comment: The assumption cannot possibly be satisfied. For $N=1$ it implies that $\ell(I_1)$ is greater or equal to $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\ell(J_k)$. So how can all $J_k$ cover all $I_n$ if (by the length argument) they cover at most $I_1$?

Comment: @freakish EIther you are misreading or misunderstanding the prompt, or I am. An example that satisfies the assumptions would be $N=1$, $I=(0,1)$, $J_k=(2^{-k},2^{1-k})$, would it not? (If your complaint is that it doesn't make sense for $N>1$, we can trivially extend this example by e.g. adding $I_2=(1,2)=J_0$.)

Comment: @SeanClark you cannot add $J_0$, indexes start from $1$. Did you mean to shift $J$s and add $I_2$ as new $J_1$? Then the equality no longer holds for new $J$s and $N=1$. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @freakish That's a pedantic complaint, simply re-index in the natural way.

And what equality are you referring to?

Comment: @SeanClark sorry, the inequality.

Comment: @freakish To elaborate, for $N=2$, we set $I_1=(0,1)$, $I_2=(1,2)$, and $J_k=(2^{1-k},2^{2-k})$. Then $\ell(I_1)+\ell(I_2)=2$, and $\sum_{k=1}^M \ell(J_k)=2-2^{1-M}$. However, I now maybe see an honest complaint in that my open cover misses powers of 2 by design, and any overlap will eventually exceed the size of the remaining interval for some $M$ rendering the inequality false. So perhaps you are correct that this cannot ever be satisfied.

Comment: @SeanClark yes, for $N=2$ your example works. But not for $N=1$ for which $\ell(I_1)=1$ is smaller than the right side. And not to mention that  you only covered two intervals, not infinitely many. Or perhaps $N$ is fixed, not arbitrary? Or maybe it is meant as "eventually"? This is confusing to me.

Comment: Wait a minute. Is $I_n$ a finite sequence and $N$ is its length? Perhaps that's what I'm missing here.

Comment: @freakish Yes, $N$ appears to be intended to be a fixed finite number of intervals $I_n$. But nevertheless I think you are right that the assumption can't be satisfied; I added some thoughts to that effect to my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Below is an argument for proving the statements with the given assumptions, but perhaps more interesting is the question of whether or not the assumptions can ever be satisfied, raised by @freakish in the comments. I believe the following argument shows they cannot hold as stated, so the statement is vacuously true.

Suppose there is a disjoint family of intervals $I_1$, $\ldots$, $I_N$ and open intervals $J_1,\ldots$  such that $\bigcup_{n=1}^N I_n \subseteq \bigcup_{m=1}^{\infty} J_m$ and yet $\sum_{n=1}^N \ell(I_n)>\sum_{m=1}^M \ell(J_m)$ for any $M$.

Let me dip into measure theory so that this argument isn't too clunky; I'll use $\ell$ for Lebesgue measure. It follows (taking limits) that $\ell(\bigcup I_n)= \sum_{n=1}^N \ell(I_n)\geq \sum_{m=1}^\infty \ell(J_m)\geq \ell(\bigcup_{m=1}^{\infty} J_m)\geq\ell(\bigcup I_n)$,
thus $\ell(\bigcup I_n)=\sum_{m=1}^\infty \ell(J_m)=\ell(\bigcup_{m=1}^{\infty} J_m)$. But since the $J_m$ are open intervals, this last equality is only possible if they are pairwise disjoint. (Otherwise, the series would be strictly larger by at least the length of any intersection.)

But if the $J_m$ are disjoint and open, they can only cover an interval $I_n$ if $I_n\subseteq J_m$ for some $m$ (otherwise, an interior endpoint of a $J_m$ is not covered), hence $I_n=J_m$ for some $m$.
But this leads to several contradictions (the cover must be finite and equal to $I$ and the inequality cannot hold).

---

Note that it suffices to show that the families $J_1,\ldots, J_M$ do not cover $\bigcup I_n$; any finite subcover includes a set $J_M$ of maximal index, and adding the finitely many missing sets $J_i$ with $i<M$  to the cover does not change it being a finite subcover.

We proceed by contradiction. Suppose there is an $M$ for which $\bigcup_{n=1}^N I_n\subseteq \bigcup_{m=1}^M J_m$. Let $J_{m,n}=J_m\cap I_n$. Note that since $I_n$ and $J_m$ are intervals, $J_{m,n}$ is an interval thus we can consider $\ell(J_{m,n})$. Since the $I_n$ are disjoint, so are the $J_{m,n}$ and thus $\ell(J_m)=\sum_{n=1}^N \ell(J_{m,n})$.

On the other hand, since $I_n\subseteq \bigcup_{m=1}^M J_m$, in particular
$I_n=\bigcup_{m=1}^M J_{m,n}$, so $\ell(I_n)\leq \sum_{m=1}^M \ell(J_{m,n})$.
But then $$\sum_{n=1}^N \ell(I_n)\leq \sum_{n=1}^N\sum_{m=1}^M\ell(J_{m,n})=\sum_{m=1}^M\sum_{n=1}^N\ell(J_{m,n})=\sum_{m=1}^M\ell(J_m)$$
which contradicts the assumption that $\sum_{n=1}^N \ell(I_n)>\sum_{m=1}^M \ell(J_m)$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\bigcup_{k=1}^N I_n \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^M J_k$ for some $M \in \mathbb{N}$, then we have 
$$\lambda(\bigcup_{k=1}^N I_n) = \sum_{k=1}^N \lambda(I_n),$$
because the intervals $I_1,\ldots,I_N$ are disjoint. On the otherhand, we have
$$\lambda(\bigcup_{k=1}^N I_n) \le \lambda(\bigcup_{k=1}^M J_m) \le \sum_{k=1}^M \lambda(J_k)$$
by monotonicity of measures and sub-additivity of measures. This is impossible, because
$$ \sum_{k=1}^N \lambda(I_n)> \sum_{k=1}^M \lambda(J_k)$$
by assumptation.